# How to handle TextInput OnChange to hide text while typing in react native?

Tags: react-native

I don't know whether questions is understood or not. My problem I have a login screen and made validations for that if `email.length === 0` now when I tap the submit button just showing an error message using `setState`.

Then Now, I want to show like a when I start to type the correct email address the error message is to disappear. In Android, we can handle this using `android: visible` or `android: invisible` property. But in react native I don't know how to solve this. Help me pls anyone.

Comment: did you try anything? any code? show us something

Comment: No, i didn't try anything just now i started browsing to find that but its confusing lot .I'm not able to get correct way to do.

Comment: Started to learn to react native based on Android concepts.

Comment: you can set the error message in your state and when text changes you can set the error message to empty in your state which will trigger a rerender. Then you can show error text based on whether the error message is present or not. You can use http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/next/docs/textinput.html#onchangetext callback. Also, remember that when you will do setState() it will rerender the whole component, so your TextInput will also get rerendered with empty data. So store the entered data also in the state and update TextInput accordingly

Answer (score 0):

If you show your message error like this

```
<Text> {this.state.msgError } <Text>
```

Then if you want to hide it when there is an email , you can simply put to the value of your state to an empty string :

```
this.setState({msgError:""});
```

Comment: Thnks for reply but I need it on OnTextChange still confusing not get proper idea